# My VLC and Parole media players cannot play a video due to missing video/x-gst-fourcc-av01 decoder?

Tags: video, vlc, codecs, av1

I get the following message when attempting to play a video file that was downloaded from YouTube:

```
video/x-gst-fourcc-av01 decoder needs to be downloaded by parole media player.
```

I have searched through the Web but have found no solution. I have `ubuntu-restricted-extras` installed and all the codecs as well. Despite all this, the video cannot be played in Parole or VLC.

My environment is Xubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I couldn't find what is needed to play in any music player. A simple solution would be to play the video through Google Chrome or Firefox. To play through browsers just drag the file into them. If you want, you can also access the files on your computer by placing **file:///home/user/directory** directly in the browser URL.

Olá amigo, tive o mesmo problema e não consegui encontrar o que é necessário pra reproduzir em qualquer reprodutor de música. Uma solução simples seria reproduzir o vídeo pelo Google Chrome ou Firefox. Pra reproduzir pelo navegadores basta arrastar o arquivo para dentro deles. Se você for quiser também dá pra acessar os arquivos do seu computador colocando **file:///home/user/diretório** diretamente na URL do navegador.

Comment: Firefox plays, but only sound, so this av01 stream (it is video) is not played

Comment: Have similar problem, browsers play video only without sound